# Do I have a dead fridge?

Tags: refrigerator

My fridge just made a noise like a tin lid hitting the floor.  Now there is no power to it at all. Circuit breaker is fine.  I can't pull it out by myself so I don't know if the outlet is ok.  Is it possible the fridge is dead.  It's only 4 years old.

Comment: do you mean even the light is out?

Comment: Yes it's out too.

Comment: well that does speak of an electric supply problem. I'd turn that breaker off until you figure it out.  Tried pulling it out? Not as hard as you  might think.

Comment: Is there a GFCI outlet in your kitchen that is tripped?  If so, try resetting it and see if your fridge turns back on.

Comment: one other option, try pushing the breaker hard into the off position than back into the on position.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is it possible the fridge is dead**

Yes.

> **It's only 4 years old**

People often say "they don't make them like they used to".

> **I can't pull it out by myself so I don't know if the outlet is ok.**

Unfortunately we can't pull it out for you from where we are. You may need to get a friend, relative, neighbour or tradesperson to help.

You can buy gadgets to make it easier for one person to slide appliances across smooth floors. There are low-cost teflon glides that you can slide under the appliances feet. These are small disks, slippery teflon (or hard plastic) on their underside, grippy rubber on the top.

[image: Photo of glides]

You can also get more substantial metal rollers.

[image: Photo of rollers]

It can help to use a length of wood on a wooden block as a lever to lift the appliance a few mm or an inch or so to slide the glides/rollers under the appliance. If doing this by yourself it might help to cut some broad shallow wedges out of wood, you can then slip these under while pressing on your lever. That holds the appliance up while you carefully position the glides or rollers.

Even getting glides just under the two front feet will often help.

If your fridge is one of those that is the size of a small car, you'll need to enlist some help from nearby people.

Comment: The gold standard is the furniture dolly.  Perhaps one can be rented.